# Running 'npm install' causes a 'npm ERR! code E401'

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I'm trying to get a co-worker set up so that she can run 'npm install'  I'm able to run it fine on my machine.

When she runs the command, it starts and appears to be running successfully for several minutes - and then dies at the very end with:

npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, need: BASIC realm="Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager"

I know that she has a recent version of nodejs installed.

I also know that she has access to our nexus repository and should have all the correct permissions.  I'm also a little surprised that it appears to be running fine and then dies right at the end.  I would think if there was an authentication error she would get it right away.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: try `npm logout` -> `npm login`

Comment: Already had her try that.  Same thing.  Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Check: https://blog.npmjs.org/post/180599338975/401-scoped-packages

> "How to fix the issue First, you can verify your token by running npm
> `whoami`. If it’s invalid or you got the 401 previously mentioned, run
> npm login to create a new token and you are good to go." 
> [npm](/questions/tagged/npm)

Comment: We are getting a lot further - thank you.  Before she was not able to run npm whoami  - now it indicates she's logged in.
Now it goes a lot longer - and then still throws the same error.